# Почему не работают push и pop (NASM)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ассемблер, nasm

Система Ubuntu x64. Версия nasm `2.15.05`.

Код запускаю командой:

```bash
nasm main.asm -f elf64 -o main.o && ld -s main.o -o main && ./main
```

Ругается на push и pop:

```
main.asm:70: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands.
```

Для примера:

```
push ax
pop ax
```

Почему возникают ошибки?

Comment: Под x64 системой в стек можно отправлять или получать только 64-битные значения (регистры в данном случае). Размер "записи" в стеке соответствует текущему режиму "битности". В данном случае, чтобы 16-битное значение положить в стек, его нужно сначала расширить до 64 бит.

Comment: Простое решение - делать push и pop регистра rax

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать! Теперь работает